# How can i split a String by last char with a regex?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I can do it like this:

```
String s = "dsad.dd.ada....png";
int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');
String[] arr = {s.substring(0, i), s.substring(i + 1)};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[dsad.dd.ada..., png]
```

But i wanna understand how can i make it with regex.

```
String s = "dsad.dd.ada....png";
String[] arr = s.split("REGEX");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [**lookahead**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertion. `(?= ... )` is a zero-width assertion which does not "consume" any characters on the string, but only asserts whether a match is possible or not.

The below regular expression first matches a literal dot then uses lookahead to assert what follows is any character except a dot "zero or more" times, followed by the end of the string.

```
String s = "dsad.dd.ada....png";
String[] arr = s.split("\\.(?=[^.]*$)");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)); //=> [dsad.dd.ada..., png]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check for last `.`

```
"\\.(?=[^.]*$)"
```

At each `.` looks, if there's only [characters, that are not](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `.` ahead until `$` end. If so, matches `.`

[Test at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/eS5mM8/1); [Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)

Answer (score 1):

This one works for all split criteria you may come up with.

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    String test = "dsad.dd.ada....png";
    String breakOn = "\\.";
    String pattern = breakOn + "(?!.*" + breakOn + ".*)";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.split(pattern, 2)));
}
```

**out:** [dsad.dd.ada..., png]